# Does JASPERPHP still works with Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, jasperstarter

I'm currently using cossou/JasperPHP, and I'm having a problem with generating the pdf file. it just gives me this error all the time `Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function` output(); `and run it manually in the console.` I tried changing the `->execute()` to `->output()` and it gives me the error that it couldn't find a pdf file.

Any other package suggestions for printing and making reports just like Crystal Report or Jaspersoft?

```
public function dbConfig(){
        //JasperPHP::compile(base_path('/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jrxml'))->execute();
        $jdbc_dir = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\TestTO\vendor\cossou\jasperphp\src\JasperStarter\jdbc';
        return [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'jdbc_driver' => 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
            'jdbc_url' => 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Employee;DataSource=(local)',
            'jdbc_dir' => $jdbc_dir
        ];
    }

    public function generateReport(){
        $jasper = new JasperPHP;

        $extension = 'pdf';
        $name = 'Employee';
        $filename = $name . time();
        $output = base_path('/public/reports/' .$filename);
        // JasperPHP::compile(storage_path('app/public'). '/reports/Employee.jrxml')->execute();

        $jasper->process(
            storage_path('app/public/reports/Employee.jasper'),
            $output,
            array($extension),
            array('id' => 1014),
            $this->dbConfig(),
            "pt_BR"
        )->execute();

        $file = $output . '.' . $extension;

        if(!file_exists($file)){
        }
        if($extension == 'xls'){
            header('Content-Description: Arquivo Excel');
            header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
            readfile($file);
            unlink($file) ;
            die();
        }
        else if($extension == 'pdf')
        {
            return response()->file($file)->deleteFileAfterSend();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya for me in laravel 8 it works fine....

I did `composer require cossou/jasperphp`

Then in

File `config/app.php`

```
<?php
//...
'providers' => [
    //...
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    //insert jasper service provider here
    JasperPHP\JasperPHPServiceProvider::class
],
```

Inside web.php
i added

```
 use JasperPHP\JasperPHP as JasperPHP;


     Route::get('/java', function () {
    
            $jasper = new JasperPHP;
        
            // Compile a JRXML to Jasper
          $t=  $jasper->compile( '/home/midhun/hi/hello.jrxml')->execute();
         
        var_dump($t);
     
            // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
            $jasper->process(
                '/home/midhun/hi/hello.jrxml',
                false,
                array("pdf", "rtf"),
                array("php_version" => "8.0.3")
            )->execute();
        
            // List the parameters from a Jasper file.
            $array = $jasper->list_parameters(
                '/home/midhun/hi/hello.jrxml'
            )->execute();
            var_dump($array);
            return view('welcome');
        });
```

After Running php artisian serve

and opening in browser localhost:8000/java

I got the pdf file

[image]

and the pdf as

[image]

Comment: I'm gonna update my question and add my code. I'm really having trouble with this.

Comment: Why doesn't it let me view the report?

Comment: What's the correct way to pass multiple objects to Jasper?